# Is there any way to use DLLs in PHP under Linux?

Tags: php, dll

As far as I know, it's only possible under Windows. But maybe, just maybe, there is some perverse way to achieve this under Linux..?

Comment: How do you load it on windows? With `dl` ? Have you read the warning?: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php

Comment: Btw this is the first hit on Google searching for `php windows dll on linux` : http://www.justskins.com/forums/accessing-windows-dll-functiond-from-linux-server-38519.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it, take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374157/using-windows-dll-from-linux).

I mean nothings impossible, you could wrap it with mono, or emulate it with WINE, but to be honest it's probably going to be an ugly solution however you spin it.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the [Windows PHP through Wine](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/wine/57825-install-dlls-wine.html).

Any specific reason for wanting to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If its web related just host it on a different box and call the DLL via a service layer.