# Use dll files in android Application

Tags: android, dll

Can I use dll files (commonly used in windows Application) in Android application?

Comment: did you managed to find a way to achieve that? or it can't happen at all? my question illustrated here if you have an answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393305/using-dll-library-in-android-application

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android runs on a Linux system - DLL files are usually bytecode compiled for Windows.

Answer (score 8):

If you have the src files for the DLL, try recompiling as an ELF32 shared object, then link that instead into your Android code (- below is a Windows solution):

---

```
set NDK_HOME=C:\Android\android-ndk-r9c   // customize this var for your own location   
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%NDK_HOME%\platforms\android-18\arch-arm\usr\lib
cd <C_SOURCE_DIRECTORY>

REM -- TEMPORARILY COPY SOME LIBS COMPILER MAY NEED  
copy %NDK_HOME%\platforms\android-18\arch-arm\usr\lib\crtbegin*.o .   
copy %NDK_HOME%\platforms\android-18\arch-arm\usr\lib\crtend*.o .

REM -- GENERATE YOUR OBJ FILE  
%NDK_HOME%\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe -g -I%NDK_HOME%\platforms\android-18\arch-arm\usr\include -c -fPIC YourLib.c -o YourLib.o

REM -- GENERATE SHARED OBJ FROM OBJ FILE  
%NDK_HOME%\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe -g -L%NDK_HOME%\platforms\android-18\arch-arm\usr\lib -shared -o YourLib_so.so YourLib_so.o

REM -- finally, remove the libraries previously copied to src directory

del .\crtbegin*.o     
del .\crtend*.o
```

---

You should now be able to use the resulting .so file in your Android project.

Answer (score 7):

DLL stands for "Dynamic Link Library" and is a Windows concept. The equivalent in linux is SO (Shared Object).

You can refer to [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/plat_ind_coding.aspx) in CodeProject for similarities and differences between the two.

This [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374157/using-windows-dll-from-linux) is pretty similar.

Comment: So, there isn't a way to achieve that ?

Comment: @Muhammed - No there isn't. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: kindly have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393305/using-dll-library-in-android-application

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wine on Linux to run programs that have dll-s. Also .apk files that you have in Android (also a version of Linux) may have dll-s if you have a run-time inside that can run those dll-s.

Unity and Xamarin both support dlls.