# How to add already compiled C library to Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have already compiled libraries (for linux(.a) and windows(.dll)). I need to import one of those (I guess for Android I will have to use .a) libraries into my android project.

So I have read some tutorials on NDK, but here is a question - do I need to have source files in order to add libraries to android or I can add already compiled?

Comment: What architecture is the .a file compiled for?  If it's x86/x64 you can't use it.  It needs to be targeted for ARM.

Comment: I am not really sure. Why cannot I use it with x86 and x64?

Comment: See Frohnzie's comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the Android NDK to recompile the library.  The ARM architecture is completely different from the x86 architecture.  The system calls are different on Linux and Windows.  It just cannot be done.

Comment: Can I recompile somehow using that static library rather than source files?

Comment: You cannot use anything compiled for another platform on Android.  No static libs, dynamic libs, or object files.  Just like you cannot use a Linux binary on Windows.

Comment: BTW question has been asked many time before. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793531/use-dll-files-in-android-application

Comment: So, the dll files can be used in Java itself using jni but can't used in android ? I stuck in that for a long time and waiting for an answer