# MT4 API on Android

Tags: android, c++, mt4

I would like to ask if it is possible to use an API ( MT4 to be exact ) and use it for creating an android app?

The MT4 API consists an header file and a DLL file.

Thank you very much.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793531/use-dll-files-in-android-application

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, it is possible.

MT4 can be run for many years already inside the WINE wrapper, so once your Android is able to use the WINE properly, voilá MT4 is fully ready for any of your advanced code-integration projects.

In the meantime, one can also use agent-based system integration, using ZeroMQ or nanomsg frameworks, that enjoy language bindings / wrappers for both ends, including the MT4 MQL4 language. Using this method very intensively for many years already to a great joy and great power of such **[distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)** applications.

Comment: Why is not this the answer?