# No DLLs inside of apk file?

Tags: android

I was trying to get the source code for a game called Pokemon Quest. When I open the apk
(https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/the-pokemon-company/)
by changing the extension to .zip, there are no DLL files. No Assembly-C.dll, but there are toms of xml files, folders, and assets. (It was written in Unity3d/has unity3d files so it should have dll files).

It's not a duplicate, as that is asking if there are dlls, I am asking why there is none in a unity app/where the code is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dll files in android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793531/use-dll-files-in-android-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of Unity projects are built using IL2CPP, what it does is convert the code to c++.

In this case you will find libil2cpp.so in your ./lib folder inside the apk.

You can try to dump the Dlls from this file using some tools like Il2CppDumper

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP.html

Answer (score -1):

Because Android is linux based.  Linux doesn't use the .dll file format.  It uses .so for C libraries.  And if the library is written in Java instead of C, it would just be a dex file.

Comment: I decompiled the dex and found a bunch of random classes but nothing relevant. The app was written in Unity3D, which creates dll files (I think).