# Giving R under Linux access to a DLL

Tags: linux, r, dll, wine

I have an R script which was developed in Windows, and which requires a particular DLL to be in the path because it uses some functions contained therein (via the `dyn.load` function).

Is it possible to make the script work under Linux? Perhaps using wine?

Comment: @VTCers: How is this not on topic?!

Comment: @bitmask: not their favorite topic i guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the source code of the non R code, I think your best bet will be to compile the code under Linux, e.g. Using a gcc compiler, create the shared library (`.so` file) and load it into R. If you put your code (R code and the other source code) in an R package you could integrate the R code and other source code so that they can be installed in one go, where the source is compiled on the fly.

---

The fact that you don't have the source code makes things quite a bit more complex. This SO post:

[Using Windows DLL from Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374157/using-windows-dll-from-linux)

Suggests to me that what you want is not trivial. One option would be to run the dll in a windows virtual machine. You then communicate using e.g. Tcp/ip to the dll running on your machine. So depending on how far you are willing to go, this might be a solution. The answers to the post above also suggest wine will not provide a satisfactory solution, but the post is quite old so wine might be improved in the meantime.

Comment: thanks for your response. Unfortunately I do not have access to the source code, I only have the binary DLL.

Comment: This complicates quite a bit, see my edited answer for more details.